# Dialog windows with Yes/No/Cancel

Tags: r

How can I create a window like the one that appears when we try to close R (With an Yes/No/Cancel button)?

`q()`

I've tried to find another function that have a window message, but did not found (and I don't know how to see the source code from `q()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use package `tcltk` to do this :

```
 library(tcltk)
 tkmessageBox(title = "Greetings from R TclTk",
         message = "Hello, world!", icon = "info", type = "ok")
 # for the one displayed by q() :
 tkmessageBox(message = "Do you want to save before quitting?",
icon = "question", type = "yesnocancel", default = "yes")
```

Look at http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/tcltk/